# NativeScript: Overlay transparent PNG frame in camera view and save the picture with the frame effect

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui, nativescript-plugin

I need to take a picture with a frame effect.
Can I preview camera image with the transparent PNG and later save the image?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [nativescript-camera-plus](https://github.com/nstudio/nativescript-camera-plus) plugin to add preview within your app, style it around with your frame.

Once the picture is taken, use [nativescript-bitmap-factory](https://github.com/mkloubert/nativescript-bitmap-factory) to create a new image that combines your frame and the actual image form camera.

Comment: Hi @manoj, I can do it with nativescript-camera-plus, but when the photo has a screen resolution, is impossible to get full camera resolution, even if I set width and height, have you any clue?

Comment: you can resize using bitmap